# Need to save jpeg file from response body in postman

Tags: json, postman

I tried to login with an application having captcha. In get method response body, the captcha is displayed in jpeg format. How to save the captcha image in my local drive from response body through script

I want to save the captcha image in my local drive from response body through script and convert the image into text for successful login
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOpb0.png)

Comment: Create another local api and pass this captcha image and save it as image using that local api.